# How to trigger/run events when using SpVoice/SpFileStream in C#

Tags: c#

I am using SpVoice to generate audio files, using SpFileStream.
I need several information about the text to be spooken, f.ex word boundaries. 
I try to add some events to execute when end of word occurs.
But the eventHandler does not run as expected.

I have tried to do as specified [here SpVoice (Events) Interface (SAPI 5.3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/)

The code:

```
    public void SpeakToFile(String toSpeak, string id)
    {
        SpVoice voiceNew = new SpVoice();
        voiceNew.EventInterests = SpeechVoiceEvents.SVEWordBoundary;
        voiceNew.Word +=VoiceNewOnWord;

        SpFileStream outStream = new SpFileStream();

        string wavPath = _fileHelper.GetTempFileNameWav(id);
        outStream.Open(wavPath, SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite, DoEvents:true);        

        voiceNew.AudioOutputStream = outStream;
        voiceNew.Speak(toSpeak);
        outStream.Close();
    }

    private void VoiceNewOnWord(int streamNumber, object streamPosition, int characterPosition, int length)
    {
        Boundary boundary = new Boundary();
        boundary.StreamPosition = streamPosition.ConvertTo<long>();
        boundary.CharacterPosition = characterPosition;
        boundary.Length = length;
        log.Info("word_boundary2: - strPos : " + boundary.StreamPosition + " - charPos : " + boundary.CharacterPosition + " - length : " + boundary.Length);
    }
```

Anyone?

Comment: Reading this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722562(v=vs.85).aspx seems to indicate event are only accessible in realtime - either while being generated or when being reproduced. You use the DoEvents optional parameter when calling the SpFileStream Open Method. If true this is a great shame - since it limits the rate at which one could produce audio with associated timed-text/subtitles.  Hope I am wrong.